dbt is unable to change the database when using dbt-sqlserver
I have been trying to integrate dbt with our SQL Server. We are using a dedicated SQL Pool. I followed the instruction to install the relevant packages. The connection was all working fine. This was confirmed by running dbt debug.
However, the dbt model fails when I try to do dbt run --select my_model. When I looked into the logs. Looks like the Fabric adapter is failing to change databases. Below is the logs:
[debug] [ThreadPool]: Opening a new connection, currently in state init
[debug] [ThreadPool]: sqlserver adapter: Using connection string: DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=myworkspacename.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydatabase;UID={admin_username};PWD=***;encrypt=Yes;TrustServerCertificate=No;APP=dbt-sqlserver/1.8.1
[debug] [ThreadPool]: sqlserver adapter: Connected to db: mydatabase
[debug] [ThreadPool]: fabric adapter: Database error: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database. (104455) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I am not sure how to go forward with this. This is my profiles.yml file:
demo:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: sqlserver
      driver: 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' # (The ODBC Driver installed on your system)
      server: myworkspacename.database.windows.net
      port: 1433
      database: mydatabase
      schema: myschema
      user: admin_username
      password: mypassword

This what dbt --version gives me:
Core:
  - installed: 1.8.6
  - latest:    1.8.6 - Up to date!

Plugins:
  - fabric:    1.8.6 - Update available!
  - sqlserver: 1.8.1 - Up to date!
  - synapse:   1.8.1 - Up to date!

I initially only had sqlserver as a plugin. But then I installed dbt-synapse also. I looked into Github for a similar issue. They said the following:

USE is supported for SQL Server and Azure SQL, but not Synapse. So whenever we see an error that has something to do with USE, it normally means that somehow dbt-sqlserver macros are being used in place of dbt-synapse's

I was wondering, if USE is supported for SQL Server, why my model is failing to be materialized?
Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Use isn't support on azure though


USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database.

The error you are getting is because Use statement is not supported in Azure SQL\Synapse server. In Azure SQL\Synapse server Cross data database query is different with on-premises SQL Server.
To resolve this issue, you can consider below approaches:

Divide your work into many phases based on the database you wish to utilize, and then connect to the appropriate database for each step.
Use another azure service to achieve tour task if possible.

